# Modifying PostgreSQL View Owner dynamiclly

Tags: postgresql

I need to modify the owner of the view as current logged in user

for eg:

```
create view test as select * from test where owner = current_user //like this
```

Can I do it like this?

Comment: Yes that should work. What problem do you have?

Comment: its saying owner column is not available.This is the error i am getting   ERROR:  column "OWNER" does not exist
LINE 45: WHERE "OWNER" = current_user

Comment: Then you need to add that column to the table `test`

Comment: i need default PostgreSQL owner to be changed dynamically

Comment: You can't change an "owner" dynamically with a select statement. I also don't understand if you intend to change the owner of the view or the owner of that table.

Comment: Because Row level Security is not working with postgreSQL 9.6 view

Comment: do I dare su assume you want to "set owner to public" for the view?.. which would be `grant all on view to public` instead?..

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the View will be the currently logged in user by default, you only have to modify it if you want the owner to be someone other than the currently logged in user.

To modify the owner you can use

`ALTER VIEW [ IF EXISTS ] name OWNER TO { new_owner | CURRENT_USER | SESSION_USER }` from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterview.html

If your intention is to apply row level security then you should apply it to the underlying table, not the view, which should restrict the returned rows appropriately to the view.

`CREATE POLICY name ON table_name
    [ FOR { ALL | SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE } ]
    [ TO { role_name | PUBLIC | CURRENT_USER | SESSION_USER } [, ...] ]
    [ USING ( using_expression ) ]
    [ WITH CHECK ( check_expression ) ]`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createpolicy.html

Comment: Ya, i agree with your answer but row level security is not working for view in PostgreSQL 9.6 even though i had applied row level security to the table to which the view is belongs to.Any way thanks for your answer.